# How to add a HTML or a PHP file, that includes a form, into Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am currently working on a Wordpress project for fun. My current problem is, that I don't know how to insert my html/php pages in to WordPress so the users could see them and I could for example, get the POST data for my queries.

Comment: Check out this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-a-wordpress-plugin-part-1

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom Template page, that contain what you like and save it into your current theme folder,

```
<?php /* Template Name: MyPage */ 
//do what you like
?>
```

after you in backend you can add a new page and select your new **Template in Page's attributes->Model**